# MVC 5 External authentication with authentication mode=Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) to create a simple MVC 5 app with external authentication. It's working fine, but, if I change the `authentication mode="None"` to `authentication mode="Forms"` it stops working.

I'm getting null on:

```
await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()
```

I'm reading a lot about something to suppress FormsAuthentication on redirect. I don't know if it's the right path, but I tried to install this [nuget packet](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) and the problem is still there.

So, why I'm getting null everytime I change the authentication mode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to get this working (OWIN and FormsAuthentication) by adding `Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true` to the `ChallengeResult` Class.

If you are following the tutorial, here is the code:

```
public class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
        : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
    {
    }

    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUri;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // this line did the trick
        context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
        }

        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks! I was screwing my head with this for long time. I can not understand why It was redirected to the login form if the ExternalLogin method is AllowAnonymous !

Comment: Almost 10 years later, you saved me from hours of stress. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would set `authentication mode="None"`, when users are not authenticated at all or if you plan to develop custom authentication code. MVC 5 has been updated to use ASP.NET Identity for authentication.

ASP.NET Identity supports claims-based authentication, where the user’s identity is represented as a set of claims. Here, you set `authentication mode="Forms"` , Claims will not work, because `ASP.NET Forms Authentication` does not support claims. That's why you get a null value.

Comment: I was able to get this working (OWIN and FormsAuthentication) by adding Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true to the actions.

Comment: I had the same issue and setting context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true after  context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider) sorted the problem.
Thank you!