# MVC 5 use old forms authentication instead of OWIN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

How can i use the forms authentication found in asp.net mvc 3/4 in mvc 5 ?

I have an mvc 4 app that i want to hook up with admin dashboard in mvc 5 and eventually convert the main app to mvc 5 but i want to keep the authentication AS IS or convert it somehow to the new auth method.

I searched for a while but all i found was on how to use the new OWIN authentication ( imo ms` version of dotnetopenauth). If you guys know a link with useful info  or can answer me here, please do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get both, OWIN and Forms, to work together by doing this: [MVC 5 External authentication with authentication mode=Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893718/mvc-5-external-authentication-with-authentication-mode-forms/19931118#19931118)