# Getting redirected to login page after disabling forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, forms-authentication

I'm kinda new to .net development and in my company, they've been using forms authentication for a while. But as we wanted to use external login integration, I implemented from the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) as given here.

Previously as my company was using **Forms Authentication** and my integration for external login being correct, I was redirected back to the login page after clicking for login with other providers.

So, I disabled authentication to None in my web.config and my external login with **OWIN** integration is working fine but now after Logging-in normally on my site it redirects me back to the login page and I'm not getting what's the issue or how can I get back both of them to work. ***I need a solution to get both forms and identity authentication to work*** or something that'll get my work done. I also got something to suppress default authentication but I'm unable to get it to work.

Comment: Forms Authentication is the old version of the authentication framework. New version is ASP.Net Identity and this is working with OWIN middleware so you can use both the normal login and the external login.

Comment: @rjs123431 but my company doesnt want to upgrade their framework as of now cause they say there are multiple dependencies. So as of now normal login works fine but fitting external login with asp.net identity doesn't and vice-versa.

Comment: The link you provided was using the Asp.Net Identity. Since this is an existing project, I guess you added the External login manually.
can you show your code for `AccountController`?

Comment: @rjs123431 was literally fed up with this issue since a month came and took a break for a couple of days and found an answer for same issue. 
 Solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19931118/12391563)